How to fix "ACRRatingInputDataSource.h file not found" AdaptiveCards IOS?
I'm currently trying to build my project on iOS and I'm using the "AdaptiveCards" library from Microsoft. However, I'm encountering an error that says "ACRRatingInputDataSource.h file not found."
I've attempted to reset the package cache and update all packages, but I'm still facing the same error.
Thanks in advance.

After a thorough investigation, I found that the issue was not caused by my application. It appears that a recent update from Microsoft introduced this bug in their product. To resolve this issue, you need to specify the last stable and functional commit in the project.yml file. This will ensure that your project uses a version of the library that is known to work correctly.
